# QGIS problem calculating area

Tags: qgis, area

I have a problem with qgis 2.8.1 (Wien). Whenever I change the project SRC to WGS84-World Mercator (EPSG 3395), the area is calculated as zero.

How can I solve this problem? Is this a known bug?

The answer from [How can I get my Qgis area calculations in metres rather than degrees? My shapefiles are projected using WGS 1984 UTM fuseau 35 Sud](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33628/how-can-i-get-my-qgis-area-calculations-in-metres-rather-than-degrees-my-shapef) don't solve the problem, since the problem only appears with a metric CRS.

[image: Printscreen of error]

Comment: Probably related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30006/how-to-calculate-polygon-areas-and-perimeters-using-qgis I feel that the layer may still have coordinate values in decimal degrees even though the CRS is 3395.

Comment: No. Even if I create a new shapefile, in a new project, both in EPSG 3395, the area calculated is 0 m². The perimeter calculated seems to be correct, just the area is zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $area works well. The problem seems restricted to the identify tool.
Gonna report this as a QGIS bug.